# How to transfer CVS from Linux to Windows

Tags: cvs

I have hard disk where is stored *cvsroot* folder with multiple files with RCS revisions (on hard disk was installed *Slackware*, but now it’s crashed). Now, I want to move this *cvsroot* folder with its content to another computer working on Windows. I never worked with cvs, so I don’t know how to make it.

After *TortoiseCVS* installing, I press on copied folder, chose – *Checkout Module*, and then I select – *locally mounted folder (:local:)”*, I get error message – *“cvs [checkout aborted]: Couldn't open default trigger library: No such file or directory*. After Windows authentication selection (:sspi:), there is error – *connect to localhost:2401 failed: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.*

Is any simple way to transfer *cvsroot* folder with content from Linux to Windows with *TortoiseCVS*, or maybe there is other program, which will let me to see differences between file version and then to export these files without RCS headers?

Thanks,
Oliver